# How much improvement should one expect to see using trickle-ICE vs ICE only

Tags: webrtc

Just read [this article](https://webrtchacks.com/trickle-ice/), which made me curious to know about the benefits in terms of speeding up the negotiation phase. I'm developing an application, where I'm using a third-party util that makes use of ICE-only, but eventually will upgrade to trickle ICE in the next version. The upgrade would require quite some code refactoring, so I would like you to share any experiences/benchmarks on this subject.

Comment: We only have about 1000-1500 customers, so my experience might not be so useful. But logging the contents of each candidate takes longer than the actual gathering, I would be amazed if trickle ICE made any noticeable difference. You might see some numbers change, but with network bandwidth being the biggest bottleneck most of the time, it really doesn  matter in practice.

Comment: There is the small chance that in trickling that if you have a TON of server off of which you gather candidates, you get a good connection candidate right off the bat and the connection could start some seconds before it usually does. However, if start up latency of a couple of seconds is not a big issue(of which their are only certain situations with trickling it would be made better), I would not even worry about it.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I decided to not use trickle ICE for now, based on your experiences :). However, as I'm turning off the WebRTC streams for muted persons, could it be an idea to maybe decrease the amount of stun servers in my list or somehow store the latest stun server used for a person (person-MCU). As I'm using a third party for this, it might not be that easy however.

Answer (score 1):

The negotiation part will get a huge speed boost using Trickle ICE. Practically it is the time since the first viable ICE candidate was found until all the ICE candidates were found.